# Modifying folder contenttypeid via REST

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, rest, csom

I have a library where a customized SPFolder content type is defined. When I use the following code in generating the folder I'm perfectly able in creating one.

However, I seem to be unable in using the base 0x0120 SPFolder content type. It automatically creates a folder with the customized content type instead of the base "Type": "SP.Folder" I'm specifying. Trying to use a MERGE REST to modify the contenttypeid also doesn't work. I also seem unable to touch the contenttypeid property, REST forces me to use the "Type" property. Why!???

```
        var foldername = folderurl;

        executor.executeAsync(
        {
            url: "url",
            method: "POST",
            body: "{ '__metadata':{ 'type': 'SP.Folder' }, 'ServerRelativeUrl':'" + foldername + "' }",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
            }
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying `ContentTypeId` in the body?

Comment: Yeah, it starts complaining it needs to be included in __metadata.

Answer (score 2):

Since Folder resource does not expose Content Type property I would recommend you to create Folder using SharePoint 2010 REST endpoint, *in that case Content Type could be specified* as demonstrated below:

```
function createFolder(webUrl,listName,folderUrl,folderContentTypeId, success, error) 
{  
     var urlParts = folderUrl.split('/');
     var folderPath = urlParts.slice(0, urlParts.length - 1).join("/");
     var folderName = urlParts[urlParts.length - 1];

     var folderPayload = {
        'Title' : folderName,
        'Path' : folderPath
     };

     $.ajax({
           url: webUrl + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/" + listName,
           type: "POST",
           contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
           data: JSON.stringify(folderPayload),
           headers: {
              "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
              "Slug": folderUrl + "|" + folderContentTypeId
           },
           success: function (data) {
              success(data.d);
          },
          error: error
     });
}
```

**Usage**

How to create a Folder named `Orders` in `Documents` library at the web site `/Archive`:

```
createFolder(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'Documents','/Archive/Documents/Orders','0x0120',
      function(folder){
        console.log('Folder ' + folder.Name + ' has been created succesfully'); 
      },
      function(error){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
      }
    );
```

> Advantages: compatible with SharePoint 2010/2013 REST Interface

### References

[Files and folders REST API reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: ¿Is posible to create it with content type name?